# Dropdown react doesn't work with Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a table and in last column I have the following drop down:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu2" type="button">Dropdown</button>
    <div aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
      <button type="button">Action</button> <button type="button">Another action</button> <button type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

When I click on drop down it doesn't open, what could the problem be?

Could it caused by the `aria` and `data` attributes?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `bootstrap.js` is loaded?

Comment: when you click on button to open dropdown menu, append `.open` class to `.dropdown-menu` and remove it when you click again. make sure to include bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js as well.

Comment: Creating a reduced test case via JS Bin and report back with your link will help to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the className attributes are working here. If you replace "className" by "class" and just add bootstrap it works.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <td>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After moving the script files (bootstrap, jquery, etc) from bottom of the file into the `<head>` bootstrap dropdowns started working.